# MongoDB Aggregation - how to generate two unique random numbers?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

The MongoDB's native shell method `_rand()` returns a number between `0` and `1`. This is used within the aggregation query, as below.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    { $addFields: { 
                   r1: { $floor: { $multiply: [ _rand(), { $floor: "$count" } ] } },
                   r2: { $floor: { $multiply: [ _rand(), { $floor: "$count" } ] } } 
    } },
] )
```

The above query returns `r1` and `r2` values between `0` and `count - 1`(i.e., `count` *minus* `1`); which is fine. Sometimes, `r1` and `r2` are same values.

How can I get two different (unique) random values (within the range of `0` and `count - 1`, for each document)? Note that the value of `count` changes for each document; but is always greater than `1`.

Sample input documents: `{ _id: 1, count: 4  }, { _id: 2, count: 2  }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the document `{ "_id" : 2, "count" : 6 }`, the possible random numbers for `count:6` are `0` thru `5`, both inclusive. Create an array with the values, `0` thru `5`, using the `$range` array operator. Generate a random number `r1` whose value is within the range of array elements, using the shell method `_rand()`.

Next, remove the `r1` value from the array. This gives an array of numbers of which we can get the second random number (and, this will not be same as the `r1`). Generate another random number `r2`, whose value is within the *index range* of the updated array.

Finally, get the *array element* at the index with value `r2`. This is the second random number (and this cannot be same as that of the first one). Now, we have two *unique* random numbers.

*References:*

- [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html)
- [_rand()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rand/index.html)
- [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

*The Query:*

```
db.rands.aggregate( 
   [ 
      { 
         $addFields: { 
            r1: { $floor: { $multiply: [ _rand(), { $floor:"$count" } ] } },
            arr: { $range: [ 0, "$count" ] }
         }
      },
      { 
         $addFields:{ 
            arr: { $setDifference: [ "$arr", [ "$r1" ] ] },
            r2: { $floor: { $multiply: [ _rand(), { $floor: { $subtract: [ "$count", 1 ] } } ] } }
         }
      },
      { 
         $project: { 
            rand_2: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$arr", "$r2" ] },
            rand_1: "$r1",
            count: 1
         }
      }
   ]
)
```